# Passing variables using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm new to Ampscript.  Can someone please explain or show an example of how I can pass a variable from 1 page to another page e.g. using form action tag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="formid_value" name="formname_value" action="%%=MicrositeURL(123456)=%%" method="Post">
    <!--emailAddress inserted in form-->
    <input type="text" name="emailAddress" id="emailAddress" value=""></input>
    <!--dateSubmitted rendered via AMPscript and assigned to hidden name/id parameter-->
    <input type="hidden" name="dateSubmitted" id="dateSubmitted" value="%%=Now()=%%"/>

    <input type="hidden" name="submit" id="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

In the above, MicrositeURL() is used to post to processing page. Going this route over having the full URL allows for leveraging app's encryption and some personalizations to be called (like emailaddr, replyfromname, etc).

On the processing page, the function RequestParameter() will be needed in order to fetch the passed value. Given the example above, it would look something like:

```
Set @submittedOn = RequestParameter("dateSubmitted")
Set @form_emailAddress = RequestParameter("emailAddress")
```

With those values assigned to a variable, what you want to do with them is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to do an HTTP post to the second page.  Insert the URL of the next page in the form tag under 'action' and once submit is pressed, all the values of the form fields will be attached as parameters to the URL (but with POST they will be hidden from User view).

On the second page, you will just use the RequestParameter() function to collect the value.You just need to make sure that the parameter you request matches exactly with the name of the field in the form you submitted.

E.G.

%%[

SET @FormValue = RequestParameter('FormValue')

]%%

You then will have the value from the previous page on the second page in the form of @FormValue variable.